# Trouble adding up string values within an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am having trouble with this one task i was assigned in school, i really can't figure it out and the teacher is not helping. I'm trying to write a program where the user inputs a certain amount of words and it counts each letter of the word then gets an average and tells the user their reading level(junior middle senior), the problem i'm having is i don't know how to write the adding up all the characters for the words that are inputted. They're strings, the words have no numbers they're just words in an array.

This is the code i have done in python so far (im beginner level)

```
WordCount=0

#Word Count Validation

WordCount=int(input("How many words are in this sentence? :"))

while WordCount <1 or WordCount >20:

    print("Up to 20 words are allowed, please try again.")

    WordCount=int(input("How many words are in this sentence? :"))

   

Words=[""]*WordCount

for i in range (WordCount):

    Words[i]=input("Please enter each word :")
```

I have tried `"".join` and sum but they arent givong me what i want, they both come out with errors or the amount of elements in the array which is not what i want
The input is meant to be how many words the user is inputting (so this can be used to do the average later) and the words that this program is meant to count, by this i mean it is meant to count each letter of the word such as how hello has 4 letters, that's the output i want and need to get the average i need for later. Im having issues with counting the letters of words which are in an array. The user can input at the start 5 and this will be used to get an average and its also the word limit, when entering the words its fully alphabetical and that only.

Comment: Can you show an example of what the user can input and what should be the result and why?

Comment: Do you want the user to input how many words are in your sentence or for the program to count the amount of words in their sentence?

Comment: So you want the user to enter a sentence, the program counts the letters in each word and then calculate the average length of each word in the sentence?

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we need to see your valiant effort so we can help you fix it. This site isn't set up as a code-writing service. We're happy to help you debug what you've written.

Comment: Ive added more to the explanation , the program is meant to count all letters in each word , add them up and then divide this number by the amount of words to get an average

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand your question correctly, you need to do these steps:

1. Get sentence from user
2. Get length of that sentence
3. Get length of each word in that sentence
4. Calculate average word length

Here's the code.

```py
user_sentence_str = input("Enter your sentence: ")
user_sentence_words = user_sentence_str.split(" ")

word_count = len(user_sentence_words)
while word_count < 1 or word_count > 20:
    print("Up to 20 words are allowed, please try again.")

    user_sentence_str = input("Enter your sentence: ")
    user_sentence_words = user_sentence_str.split(" ")

word_length_sum = 0
for word in user_sentence_words:
    word_length_sum += len(word) # Adds length of the current word to the sum

average_word_length = word_length_sum / word_count
print(f"The average word length in your sentence is {average_word_length}.")
```

Basically, this code takes in a sentence as a string and splits it by spaces to form a list of the words (lines 1+2).

It then checks if the word_count is less than 1 or greater than 20 and asks for a new sentence if its outside this range.

Next, it loops over all the words in the sentence and adds its length to a variable.

Finally, it calculates the average word length by dividing the sum of the word lengths by the word count and prints it out.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you.

```
    # Get user input
    user_sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")

    # split sentence into the list of words
    words = user_sentence.split()

    # initialize a dictionary to store wordwise lengths
    word_lengths = {}

    for word in words:
            # Removing punctuation (depending on your requirements)
            word = word.strip(".,?!")

            # Counting letters in each word & stores into dictionary
            word_lengths[word] = len(word)

    # print wordwise lenght
    for word, count in word_lengths.items():
        print(f"{word}: {count}")

    #calculate average of the letters per word
    average_of_letters = sum(word_lengths.values()) / len(word_lengths)

    print(f'the average of letters: {average_of_letters}')
```